# ios add multiple markers on the map using GMSMarker

Tags: ios, google-maps

Hello I am trying to add two markers on the map every time I tap.First marker is circle and second is triangle. But when I tap for the second time, first marker gets removed and new marker is added. I want to keep both. (And then connect these markers to different points but you can ignore that)
My code is:

```
-(void)addMarkerInTheMapView:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
if (arrayHolesData.count == 0 || arrayHolesData == nil || [arrayHolesData isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ) {
    return;
}


// marker for circle point

markerCirclePoint = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
[markerCirclePoint setDraggable: YES];
// Use some kind of data to identify each marker, marker does not have 'tag' but 'userData' that is an 'id' type
markerCirclePoint.zIndex = 3;
markerCirclePoint.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude );
markerCirclePoint.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"target.png"];
markerCirclePoint.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
markerCirclePoint.map = mapViewGoog;


// add triangle marker
if(isTriangleSelected == YES)
{
    markerTrianglePoint = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    [markerTrianglePoint setDraggable:YES];
    markerTrianglePoint.zIndex = 4;
    markerTrianglePoint.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude );
    markerTrianglePoint.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rangefinder.png"];
    markerTrianglePoint.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    markerTrianglePoint.map = mapViewGoog;

}
```

}

This code is executed when I tap:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
if (arrayHolesData.count==0 || arrayHolesData==nil || [arrayHolesData isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ) {
    return;
}




   [mapViewGoog clear];

markerMYFlagLable = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
markerMYFlagLable.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lot4, lon4);
markerMYFlagLable.icon = iconNew;
markerMYFlagLable.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0,1);
markerMYFlagLable.map = mapViewGoog;

// Creating FirstLine from current location to tap

GMSMutablePath *pathCurrentToTapp = [GMSMutablePath path];
[pathCurrentToTapp addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude_Point,longitude_Point)];
[pathCurrentToTapp addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];

rectangleFirst = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:pathCurrentToTapp];
rectangleFirst.strokeWidth = 2.f;
rectangleFirst.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
rectangleFirst.map = mapViewGoog;

// Creating FirstLine from flag to tap



pathflagToTapp = [GMSMutablePath path];
[pathflagToTapp addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[dicCor objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue],[[dicCor objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue])];
[pathflagToTapp addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];
rectangleSecond = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:pathflagToTapp];
rectangleSecond.strokeWidth = 2.f;
rectangleSecond.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
rectangleSecond.map = mapViewGoog;


    //creating path from triangle to flag
   if(isTriangleSelected == YES)
    {
        pathCircleToTriangle = [GMSMutablePath path];
        [pathCircleToTriangle addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];
        [pathCircleToTriangle addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude_Point, longitude_Point)];

        rectangleThird = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:pathCircleToTriangle];
        rectangleThird.strokeWidth = 2.f;
        rectangleThird.strokeColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        rectangleThird.map = mapViewGoog;
    }


[self addMarkerInTheMapView:coordinate];
```

}

Comment: remove '[mapViewGoog clear];'. This ll clear all the markers on the map

Comment: @Bharath yeah i understood but i need it to display first marker. that means only two markers will be displayed on the map. How do i do that?

Comment: Okey so if I assume, your first marker is something that doesnt change its position but the second marker keeps on changing based on the location you typed. isnt ?

Comment: when i tap for the second time, I dont want first marker to change its position but it does.